# Pop-ups behave differently on actual machine

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, popup

We are working on a desktop application developed on swings with MVC framework.

The problem I am having is weird.  The application shows the pop-ups properly on the dev's box.  But the same application when deployed on to the actual machine behaves in-appropriately.  The pop-ups seem to be appearing but they close in a fraction of a second.

To better explain it here is an example:

1. We show a progress pop-up
2. We prompt a confirmation window.
3. Open the progress pop-up.
4. Again open the progress pop-up with a different text.
5. Open a different confirmation window.
6. Progress pop-up again.

All the instances of the pop-ups are singleton.  And we are making sure to reset each instance before displaying other pop-up.  We even thought it might be because of timer issues and put all of the pop-ups in invokeLater.  Nothing is working on the client machine.

We tried to remote debug it,  when we do that,  the application is working fine with all the pop-ups displaying properly in a sequence.

Once it actually runs by itself.  Some of the pop-ups will be visible and the others just close in a fraction of a second and re-appear in the next transaction when its time to show some other pop-ups.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: This really sounds like a timing issue. Can you post some code that replicates this behavior?

Comment: first I would find out all the differences between the dev and deploy box: OS, jdk ... Next try to code a small SSCCE reproducing the problem on the client box. With that example and the context info, someone here with a box nearto the actual client might be able to track it down

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using [`isPopupTrigger()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html#isPopupTrigger%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) the way they show in the section [Bringing Up a Popup Menu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup).